# Using shell_exec to run python script in a PHP file works when using localhost but not when put on the server

Tags: python, php, server, localhost, shell-exec

I am quite new to web development and have been trying to run some Python code via a PHP script. When working on my localhost, shell_exec works great. However, when putting it on the server (Hostinger), the Python script does not work.

I thought this might be the case because on the localhost it uses the Python installed on my computer, but I am not sure what is the best way around this.

Thank you!

Comment: It seems like Hostinger automatically disables shell_exec and you have to manually add it back

Comment: You should add more details - how do you exactly execute your script (I mean, do you type `python3 script.py` or using full paths) and result code and/or errors from script. Enable error reporting and try again.

Comment: I use `shell_exec('python python/file.py ')`

Comment: @2C0C7 Right. Many hosting providers do limit the use of `shell_exec`, `proc_open` and the like (i.e. generally, [exec functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php)), using [`disable_functions` ini directive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions), to prevent possible exploits. Plus, many providers provide only PHP. This means, for example, you might not have Python executable in your environment, even if you could access a shell. If you're using PHP 7.4+, [FFI](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ffi) might help you, however I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to enable shell_exec and narrowed down the problem to actually being the imported files in the python document. At the top of `file.py`, I am importing a few libraries e.g. `import sys, math, numpy`. Unfortunately, these are not working